# Keep OSX from switching Keyboard layout automatically

Tags: macos, keyboard, layout

I’m not using a normal Apple Keyboard on my Mac. It’s a standard ISO keyboard with a German Layout. Unfortunately this keyboard is not supported by OSX by default. So some keys are not working right. Apple uses some different layout for special characters. So I created my own keyboard layout and installed it on OSX. This is working just fine. I have a symbol in the menubar to switch the layout. This is necessary because I also have the internal keyboard of the MacBook that is using the Apple layout.

The problem is that my layout works fine for most applications. But there a some that keep switching the layout to the Apple default one. For example the Apple Mail App or Parallels Desktop. This drives me nuts: Some applications have a different layout.

In the system setting there is an option for the input source. I set it to “Use the same one in all documents”. But it still changes the layout in Mail. The funny thing is that if Mail is active I can’t switch the keyboard layout manually. I can select it, but it just won’t switch it.

Hope somebody can help me.

Comment: I’ve got the same problem.  Only with Mail, all other applications use the right keyboard layout.  What did you use to create the custom keyboard layout?  I used [Ukulele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=ukelele)

Answer (score 1):

If the keylayout is in `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts/`, try moving it to `/Library/Keyboard Layouts/`. It normally enables using keyboard layouts in password dialogs and the login window.

You can also disable the default input sources by [editing the HIToolbox plist](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44921/how-to-remove-or-disable-a-default-keyboard-layout/60521#60521).